# Default video app keeps resetting from MPV on MacOS

Tags: macos, video, file-association, mpv

### The Problem

I use the [`mpv`](https://mpv.io) video player to play all videos on my mac, though I also have `VLC` installed. The problem is that after a while my default video application changes to VLC (and/or Quicktime, depending on the file type/extension) without any apparent reason and trying to change it back gives an error.

---

### What it looks like

The whole process is a *bit weird* and this doesn't happen always, but when it does, it looks like this every single time:

1. I double click on a video file, and it opens up in `mpv` (since it is set as the default video application for a lot of formats i.e. `mkv`, `mp4`, etc.)
2. The video ends (or I close it) and open another video. It opens in `VLC`. At this point, the video file icons still identify `mpv` [as the default application and are listed under it](https://jmp.sh/0NvgsJ8) in Finder, until I change directories.
3. I open `Get Info / Inspector` to set the default app (It correctly [shows the VLC video icon](https://jmp.sh/fMTqZCL) since that is the default at this point).
4. Here's the *Weird Thing 1*: **`mpv` is greyed out in the application list** (It's not usually).

   [image: MPV greyed out]
5. But still selecting `mpv` and clicking `Add` gives this error:

   > **You can't change the item "My Video.mkv" to always open in the selected application.**
   >
   > The item is either locked or damaged, or in a folder you don't have permission to modify (error code -9499).

   [image: Error on changing default video app]

6. Here's the *Weird Thing 2*: Since I have no choice but to close inspector at this point, **mpv becomes the default app automatically** after closing it. But when opening a video, the OS thinks that I am opening MPV for the first time and shows this dialog:

   > **You are opening the application "mpv" for the first time. Are you sure you want to open this application?**
   >
   > The application is in a folder named "HEAD-xxxxxxx". To see the application in the Finder without opening it, click Show Application.

   [image: Running mpv the first time]
7. The thing to note here, is that if I don't even attempt to change the application, `VLC` (or QuickTime) would remain the default. So even though I was unable to "successfully" set `mpv` as the default, it becomes the default as soon as I close the file `Inspector / Get Info` dialog.
8. `mpv` remains the default video app for an indeterminate period of time until it happens again

---

### Reproducing It

While this has been happening for months now, I've been unable to consistently reproduce the issue or pinpoint the cause. *It just happens™️*, sometimes twice in one day, sometimes after weeks.

---

### What I've tried

- Tried upgrading MPV
- Completely removed and tried installing from different sources

  - Homebrew binary with bundle (using this currently)
  - Homebrew cask
  - Compiled release from the official website/github

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know this is an old question, but I've been having issues with mpv on MacOS too. Have you tried setting the default program from the terminal? The following worked for me:

```
$ brew install duti
$ duti -s io.mpv avi all
$ duti -s io.mpv mkv all
$ duti -s io.mpv mp4 all
```

I needed to install mpv from its cask.

Source:
[mpv FAQ](https://github.com/mpv-player/mpv/wiki/FAQ#How_can_I_make_mpv_the_default_application_for_opening_movie_files_on_macOS_OSX)

Comment: The problem resolved itself after a couple of updates of mpv. But I still like this approach to set defaults for all media files.